# Create tags object from array in mongo collection for Select2 options

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo collection with a array field called 'tags'.  What I want to do is create a single object that stores all of the various tags with a label and value.  The end result should be an object I can use in a Select2 field in a Meteor application to create the results options.   I have gotten close, but all of my solutions have not worked and are super ugly (read: not functional javascript)

Here is a sample document:

```
{
"_id":  "sjkjladlj",
"title": "Coldplay is Cool",
"tags": ["music", "yuppie"]
}
```

Now the end result I would like is:

```
[
{
value: "music",
label: "music"
},
{
value: "yuppies",
label: "yuppies"
},
{
value: "Some tag from another doc"
label: "Some tag from another doc"
}
]
```

Any ideas?

Here is the closest I have gotten.

```
options: function() {
          tagsArray = [];
          ca = Notes.find({}, {tags: 1}).fetch();
          ca.forEach(function(it) {
            result = {};
            result = it.tags;
            tagsArray.push(result);
          });
          console.log(tagsArray);
          return tagsArray;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with aggregation pipeline like this

> db.colleaction.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,tags:1}},{$unwind:"$tags"},{$project:{"value":"$tags","lable":"$tags"}}])

Answer (score 0):

**Update. As soon as I posted I realized I simply need to add a inner loop.   Its ugly, but it works.**

```
options: function() {
          tagsArray = [];
          ca = Notes.find({}, {tags: 1}).fetch();
          ca.forEach(function(it) {
            result = {};
            result = it.tags;
            result.forEach(function(child){
              inner = {};
              inner.value = child;
              inner.label = child;
              tagsArray.push(inner);
            });
          });
          console.log(tagsArray);
          return tagsArray;
        }
```